# simple htaccess RewriteRule to map 404 URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this URL:

```
mysite.com/index.php?pageType=404
```

and then I want it to get mapped to:

```
mysite.com/404
```

I have written the following rewrite rule but it does not work, what is the problem?

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule mysite.com/404 mysite.com/index.php?pageType=404
IndexIgnore *
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need `RewriteRule ^404/?$ /index.php?pageType=404`. RewriteRule _pattern_ doesn't match for host `mysite.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule`'s first argument is a regex that matches everything behind the domain name and before the query string. For an url like `http://example.com/my/site/is/awesome?give=mecookies`, it would match `my/site/is/awesome` (without the first slash).

The correct rule would be:

```
RewriteRule ^404$ index.php?pageType=404 [L]
```

Please read [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information about this.